# How to make a dynamic server based in-app/in-game store for an iPhone game (like Contract Killer 2)?

Tags: iphone, ios, dynamic, in-app-purchase, server-side

I see that many iOS games nowadays don't hardcode their store, and items, description, price etc. are loaded from an external server.

What would be the easiest way to implement this? I am a game programmer with very little experience in server side programming. (Have done hobby PHP scripts a long time ago)

Please let me know what libraries can ease the effort on server side / client side. I would like something that is easy to manage. How do they announce offers like 50% off on certain items etc. whenever they want? Doesn't every in-app purchase manipulation need to get approval from Apple?

Also I would want to maximize security, and prevent the game store getting hacked as much as possible.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how in-app purchases work, but it is a possibility to do an HTTP request to a PHP script to query a database to return a JSON response to be parsed in app? Do all in-app items need to be updated through the App Store?

Comment: @MattClark Apparently yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that this has to go through Apple's IAP.  You'll want to read about this at https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html.  You setup the IAP items in iTunesConnect (iTC).  Your in-app store lists only items that you've setup in iTC, though you can choose not to list every item in ITC.  To make your store dynamic, the easiest way is probably to use a UIWebView and then have your store be a series of webpages.  This lets you update it on your server easily.

You might check out http://stackmob.com which makes it relatively easy to do just the store part of your in-game store without having all the server admin aspect of it (and associated security).  Also, http://urbanairship.com provides hosting for IAP items.

Comment: Thanks for the details and links. Will go through them. We already checked UrbanAirship. It costs about 1000$ to send one push notification to 1Million users. Will I be able to save a lot of server cost if I do this myself?

Comment: I know UA is not the cheapest in the world. Seems like things are somewhat less expensive in India so maybe you could get a better price locally.  You might also check out https://parse.com/plans  for the push notifications.  They don't do html file hosting (for your store), but you could host those pages anywhere.

Comment: Also thank you very much for the direction of using a UIWebView for the entire store. For some reason I never thought you could handle button events and javascript events raised inside UIWebView. But some quick googling revealed I can call an Objective C method from a javascript event raised from inside a UIWebView.

While I will consider this method. We also don't want to depend on a Web designer/developer each time we change the store. We will either have to develop a template based web app for it or just go with native views.

Comment: If you want to do native then just have the server side return XML or JSON with the data of what you want to appear in the store.  Then your native code parses that and decides what to show in the store.  The XML/JSON will likely contain urls to the images for items in the store which you'll want to asynchronously fetch from the server and cache locally.

Comment: If you want to go really cheap you could just have the app fetch an xml file from a static web server (apache or whatever) and edit that file by hand and ftp it to the server when you want to update it.  Put the images for item on the same static page web server and include appropriate urls to them in the xml file.  Most people would use a database on the server and some web pages to make it easier to edit and have some server code that does a query on the web pages and generate XML to return to the app, but it's not necessary for a small store. Static pages will be faster to serve anyway.